# Creating asp.net page with user profile

Tags: asp.net, textbox, grid

I am creating asp.net website where my customers will get register by filling out a form. The form has name, address, phone no,email etc. Now I want to provide facility for user to enter more than one phone number and also more than one email if he want to enter. So how the design should be? Should I provide more number of textbox? But it will not look good. Should I display a new textbox to appear automatically when one phone number is entered(may be using grid etc). So how these kind of things are done in general? I also want to include validation for phone number and email field. So it became some what difficult to design. Otherwise user can enter with comma separator or space etc. But validation will become difficult because user may enter anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest scenario would be to allow one extra phone number and email field, maybe label them "Alternative Phone" and "Alternative Email".

If you want more than 1 alternative for each I would provide a "+" button which unhides textboxes to allow another number/address to be entered. In this case you would want to initially set the extra rows hidden using css and attach javascript to the onlick event of the "+" button to unhide them.